# A Cauchy problem for an iterated Euler-Poisson-Darboux equation

Tags: linear-pde, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I'm interested in solving a Cauchy problem for the iterated singular EPD.

Weinstein ([On a class of PDEs of even order](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02410772), 1955) showed how the decomposition formula leads to the solution of the Cauchy problem for the iterated wave equation (so, for $k=0$).

My question, how one can use this decomposition to solve a Cauchy problem for the iterated EPD equation?

$L_kL_m u(t,x)=0$,

$D_t^i u(0,x)=u_i(x) , 0\leq i\leq 3 \\ $,

where $L_k := D^2_t-D^2_x+ \frac{k}{t}D_t$

Comment: I assume EDP-> PDE?

Comment: EPD : Euler-Poisson-Darboux

Answer (score 1):

Is it not simply a conversion of an iterated homogeneous equation into a non-iterated non-homogeneous equation? By hypothesis, $L_m u = v$, where $L_k v = 0$. Every such $v$ can be obtained from some initial data at $t=0$. On the other hand, every every such $u$ can be obtained by solving the inhomogeneous linear equation, using advanced and retarded Green functions for $L_m$, plus some solution $w$ of the homogeneous equation $L_m w = 0$. Then the freedom in the choice of $w$ is fixed by matching the initial conditions for $u$ at $t=0$. Thus, to solve the iterated problem, you need only know how to solve the homogeneous and inhomogeneous non-iterated problems.

Are you perhaps looking for some explicit formulas for the Green functions that match initial conditions to the solutions that result from this procedure?

**Update.** About the choice of initial conditions. BTW, I didn't immediately pay attention to the fact that you want the initial data specified at $t=0$, which is the location of the singularity of the coefficients of your PDE. This is a kind of [Fuchsian equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuchsian_equation#Fuchsian_differential_equation) that requires extra care when imposing boundary conditions. I haven't examined this example in detail yet, but you may not be able to specify all the derivatives, $0\le i \le 3$, while requiring the solution to stay bounded at $t=0$. First, let me illustrate how to determine all the initial conditions when $t=0$ is a regular value for the coefficients. I may come back to the singular case later.

Write your solution as $u = u_v + w$, where $L_m w = 0$, $L_m u_v = v$ and $L_k v = 0$. You are free to set the initial conditions $D_t^{0,1}w(0,x) = u_{0,1}(0,x)$ and $D_t^{0,1} u_v(0,x) = 0$. Then the first two initial conditions are met, $D_t^{0,1}u(0,x) = u_{0,1}(0,x)$. On the other hand, just by taking time derivatives you find that $D_t^{0,1}v(0,x) = D_t^{0,1}L_m u_v(0,x) = D_t^{0,1}L_m u(0,x)$, where the right hand side can be determined from the knowledge of the derivatives $D_t^i u(0,x)$, $0\le i \le 3$. This gives you the initial conditions for solving $L_k v = 0$.

Comment: @Igor, thank you very much. Indeed, it is easy to solve the non-homogeneous iterated equation. But, how shoold we choose the initial condition for $L_m u=v$ such that the solution of (auxiliary) second order EDP satisfies both the iterated EDP and the four initial conditions?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure I understand your initial onditions. How are you specifying the values of the 0th-3rd time derivatives at $t=0$ needed to fix a unique solution?

Comment: for the sake of brevity, let me take $u_0(x)=x^n$, $n$ is a positive integer, and $u_1(x)=u_2(x)=u_3(x)=0$. 

Comment: Ah, I see now. The $D^i u(0,x)$ should have been $D^i_t u(0,x)$ in your question.

Comment: yes, as you said